# How strong is the inflationary force of the universe's rotational variations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, inertial-frames, spring, machs-principle

Let a universe comprise two identical point masses connected by a short massless spring.  Suppose somebody reaches in and spins them around their shared centre.  Naive mechanics says the spring stretches.

But that depends on the notion of a "fixed space or ether" - a very old idea, currently not in favour.  More fashionable today is the relativistic view, which says rotation can only be measured relative to the contents of the universe, and since in the above description we've spun the entire universe, the reference frame is now rotating so in actual fact the masses are stationary in relation to their reference frame, not spinning at all, and the spring remains unstretched.

Now return it to rest and add two further masses, these two are connected by a LONG massless spring.  All four masses are in line and the two spring centres coincide, and for the sake of abstraction, let's assume they can all pass through each other freely.

Now suppose somebody reaches in and spins the outer two masses.  Classical mechanics says the longer spring stretches.  But our "more fashionable argument" says it won't stretch by quite so much because the universe is now spinning in the same direction.  In fact taking into account the frame of reference our shorter spring now also stretches despite us not having touched it, because its reference frame is turning relative to it.

Whatever, we have to conclude that holding objects in orbits pulls some other objects apart - correct?  In fact, there must be a measure - let's call it the **moment of torsion** in the universe, which reflects the derivative of angular momentum with respect to distance from the universe's centre, and this moment will correspond with in inflationary force.  How strong is this inflationary force across the perceivable universe?

Answer (score -1):

If the universe is comprised of two masses and a string, **somebody** can't do anything, because **somebody** isn't two masses and a string and isn't part of the universe.

The Third Law plus prohibits us from rotating everything in a universe, even a toy universe with nothing in it but the rocket and its exhaust, therefore it's not clear that "rotate everything in the universe" means anything at all, and there's no experiment which could be done to do it, even if we populate the universe with invisible rocket wizards first. I do find it metaphysically satisfying to suppose that there is no such thing as absolute rotation, only rotation with respect to the rest of the contents of the universe, creating a satisfying parallel with translation. But since there is no experiment which can be proposed which would test the hypothesis (even in a fictitious toy universe), that isn't a statement about physics, and rotation in physics is absolute.

Comment: My first two paragraphs say the naive idea of rotating the entire universe is nonsensical and explain why.  Yet you have stated that fact to me as if I did not say it first.  Then you say rotation in physics is "absolute". What physics is this and do you have a reference for this statement?  To my eye the statement is contradictory to your claim that the third law prevents us from rotating everything within a universe.

Comment: @samerivertwice And you, have you a reference for saying that rotation is relative ? Rotation is an imaginary boost.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux I'm happy for the reader to take the view rotation is relative or absolute. The notion it is absolute is equivalent to saying there is an ether, fixed independently of the other matter in the universe, against which things rotate. This is a very old debate, it's the relativity debate and as I say, I'm happy for a reader to take either view or to be silent on the matter - as is their will. Where I put "superior argument" I should maybe have put - the current dominant or preferred view among the majority. In fact I've now edited the question.

Comment: @gs In light of the edit this may affect your answer.

Comment: @samerivertwice the definition of a universe prevents us from doing anything (even measuring) to a universe of which we are not a part because if we aren't part of everything that exists, *we don't exist*. If you define the toy universe to include us so that we can do things to it, momentum and angular momentum are conserved wherever they are defined.

Comment: Putting the test region in a metaphorical box with a little hole in it for the scientist to look through, then doing things to the test region and seeing how things play out, has been enormously successful for both practicing and teaching science. The intuition thus built is to apply the same technique to questions about the universe. We'll just put *everything* (or a tiny toy model of everything) in a box, isolate the (tiny toy model) scientist from it, and do have the scientist do things to it to see how things play out. But that's logically incoherent.

Comment: Since a rotation is a collection of accelerations, and accelerations are perturbations of a trajectory from a geodesic, and geodesics include information about the motion of all the masses in the universe, there's a sense in which rotation can be seen as relative to the motion of all masses in the universe - but rotation of one thing and everything else can't just be switched by defining a coordinate system that doesn't measure the rotation of the one thing, which is what we mean by relativity in translation.

Comment: Consider that in the real universe, any angular velocity greater than 1 radian per 44 billion years would result in most of the universe translating faster than the speed of light in a corotating coordinate system.

Comment: In any case, as I've said: even in a tiny toy model universe, there's no experiment we (or arbitrarily well prepared space wizards) can do to take an isolated test object, spin up the rest of the universe around it, and see if it measures a centrifugal force, because momentum is conserved. Questions about what would happen if a thing happened that can't happen are not questions about physics.

Comment: @gs I only introduce the notion of reaching in and spinning the universe as an edifice with which to isolate the two rotations. Are we in agreement that the universe can be seen as a system, which can be partitioned into two parts along some arbitrary axis through a notional centre - then one can pick a "distance" from the centre around which the rotation momentum of the outer part is equal and opposite to the rotational momentum of the inner? That is all we need to agree upon in the real world in order for the question to be meaningful.